# jquery sortable not working when adding new div

Tags: arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

sorry i lot of question than contribute the answer
because i don't know so many kind of web programming
i tried jquery sortable, i really don't know how jquery sortable work
my code is working before, until i add new element `<div class="grid_12">` on top like this :

```
<div id="list">
<div class="parent ui-sortable">

    <div class="grid_12">
    <h2 id="arrayorder_1">Home</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_12">
    <h2 id="arrayorder_2">Profil</h2>
    </div>

</div>        
</div>
```

and the message :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

the sortable does not produce an array, here my jquery sortable script

```
$(function() {
    // uiSort utama parent
    $('#list .parent').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.8,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        cursor: 'move', 
        update: function() {

            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
            $.post("updateList.php", order, function(theResponse){

            alert(theResponse);

            });                                                              

        }                                 
    });
    });
```

please answer this foo.. thanks ^^'

Comment: I put your code unchanged into a jsfiddle and it appears to work. https://jsfiddle.net/tauukLe2/
The error is in some other part of your code that you didn't show, or maybe in the PHP call.

Comment: code is working before, and the php call too.. i only adding <div class="grid_12"> for container div and sortable doesn't work foreach call

Comment: Understood, but I can't reproduce the problem with the code you showed, even though it includes the grid_12 element. So the problem seems to exist in code that isn't shown.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: look at the jsfiddle I posted, and compare to your code. Can you add code to the jsfiddle to make it look more like your code? And if you do, does it start to fail?  Or do the reverse: remove or comment out your code to make it look more like the jsfiddle, until it starts to work. That will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: You should also compare the jsquery and jsqueryui versions I used in the fiddle to the ones you are using in your code. Maybe there's an important difference there.